# Custom route defaults to Index view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a view at `/Folders/Index`. I wanted to be able to navigate to `/Folders` instead, as well as pass an id, like `/Folders/123`. So I created this route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "",
    url: "Folders/{parentFolderId}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Folders", action = "Index",
        parentFolderId = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

This did work for the situations specified above.

The problem is that if I try to navigate to `/Folders/Create`, it just renders my `Index` view.

How can I change my route to work correctly?

I'm very new to the routing system, so apologies if this is a simple answer, but I thought this would do the trick. Also, could someone direct me to a good resource for learning how to do these on my own?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to use two routes to resolve this situation - first to match "/Folders/Id" and second to resolve "/Folders/Action"

```
routes.MapRoute(
name: "",
url: "Folders/{parentFolderId}",
defaults: new { controller = "Folders", action = "Index",
    parentFolderId = UrlParameter.Optional },
constraints: new { parentFolderId = @"^[0-9]*$" });

routes.MapRoute(
name: "",
url: "Folders/{action}",
defaults: new { controller = "Folders", action = "Index"});
```

**EDIT:**
If you want to map any parentFolderId parameter without constraint then you should first map create action and then parentFolderId.

```
routes.MapRoute(
name: "",
url: "Folders/Create",
defaults: new { controller = "Folders", action = "Create"});

routes.MapRoute(
name: "",
url: "Folders/{parentFolderId}",
defaults: new { controller = "Folders", action = "Index",
    parentFolderId = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Comment: Constraints in first route is important because than first route won't match "/Folders/Create"

Comment: If you want to match parentFolderId without any constraint then you should put Create action route map before "Folders/{parentFolderId}" route map.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "",
    url: "Folders/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Folders", action = "Index" }
);
```

Comment: How is this different than the default route?